# \vfill on parcolumns is not working

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am trying to follow this template on Overleaf. As you can see, the left column is aligned to the bottom of the paper but I can't seem to get it on mine.

[image: Awesome looking research paper]

Here's my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{parcolumns} 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}

\begin{titlepage}

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={1=0.3\textwidth}]{2}
\colchunk
{
\newpage
\null\vfill
\flushright
\textbf{REPORT DETAILS} \\
\textit{\textbf{Started on:}} \\
December 16, 2020 \\
\textit{\textbf{Completed on:}} \\
December 20, 2020
\textit{\textbf{Submitted on:}} \\
February 1, 2021
}

\colchunk
{
\flushleft
\fontsize{22}{28}\selectfont Algorithm for De-noising Vocal Signals with FIR Digital Filter using MATLAB \\
}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image: Not awesome school report]

I am dying. It's 6 in the morning and I still can't get this fixed. Please help. I seriously don't understand how something that looks so simple can be so difficult to do. I could probably get this done on Word in 1/10th the time it took me to try and fix this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you currently write a paper which you would like to submit to this specific journal or do you just want to replicate the look of the paper for a different project? If the former is the case, you might want to use the official latex template from the publisher instead. (https://www.frontiersin.org/about/author-guidelines, https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-frontiers-journal/myxxkvjwqhrv)

Comment: I want to replicate the look of the paper for a different project.